# Laravel localization issue

Tags: laravel

Base on [laravel official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#pluralization) I've made pluralization translation like:

```
{{__('store.cartitems')}}
```

and language file like:

```
'cartitems' => '{1}Item|[2,*]Items',
```

the result i get is:

```
Cart 3 {1}Item|[2,*]Items
```

as documentation says it suppose to say `3 Items` instead it return my translation full value.

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your language file according to the code below.

```
'cartitems' => '{1} :items Item|[2,*] :items Items',
```

This allows you to use the localization on the view like so:

```
{{ trans_choice('store.cartitems', $cartItems->count(), ['items' => $cartItems->count()]) }}
```

Comment: thanks it's working, but why the documentation way doesn't work?

Comment: Actually the documentation says, that when using a translation string which introduces pluralization, you must use the `trans_choice` method in order for it to work.